Is it possible to make a build flavor "non-combinable" dimension-wise in Android build.gradle configuration?
I have encountered a problem while configuring an Android app build.gradle's build variants.
As a rule, all build flavors are being combined to all other build flavors with different dimensions in M:M relationship. So, for the code:
flavorDimensions = ["letter", "digit"]

productFlavors {
    alpha {
        dimension "letter"
        isDefault true
    }
    beta {
        dimension "letter"
    }
    one {
        dimension "digit"
        isDefault true
    }
    two {
        dimension "digit"
    }
}

we get the following build variant collection (let's ignore the debug/release build types for brevity):

alphaOne (default);
alphaTwo;
betaOne;
betaTwo.

But can I exclude one particular flavor from being combined with anything? So I could get another list of variants, for example:

alphaOne (default);
alphaTwo;
beta.

I have been searching for any clue in docs and google for quite a while but didn't find anything on this matter.

https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#filter-variants

@tim_yates but this will only allow us to eliminate the combined flavors. I want to also save the singular flavor like in the example in the question. So I have not the [a1, a2, b1, b2] but [a1, a2, b] flavors collection instead.
